# In AWS Cloudformation I am getting an error like "Parameters of resource [ABC] don't match with the actual parameters of nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using Cloudformation stackset wherein I have imported existing resources like SQS queues and S3 bucket into my nested CFT(Cloudformation) stack.

Now I am trying to import top-level CFT stack, so that above CFT stack can be referred as a nested stack. So, I pushed this nested stack into S3 bucket so that top-level CFT can refer it.

Now, while importing top-level CFT, I am providing the stack ID of my nested stack and also giving all values of the parameters whichever are required and I have ensured the parameters and its values are in sync with nested stack. But still I am getting below error.

```
Parameters of resource [ABC] defined in the template don't match with the actual parameters of arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:<account_ID>:stack/nested-stack/1dr5tgh7-4213-vy67-1aq4-67hj09pnjhf.
```

I have verified parameters and its values number of times and its same. There is no difference but still I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Can anyone please help me to git rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

AWS support helped identify parameter mismatch. I had a String parameter that accepts `Yes/No` values. When I was passing in `Yes` without quotes, internally cloudformation was translating it to `true` boolean value.
Thus the mismatch.
Fix for me, is to enclose the parameter value in quotes as `"Yes"`.